# Finding & factoring a derivative.

Tags: calculus

I am looking to find and factor the deriviate of f(x) = $x(x+3)^3$

I can find the derivative but I need to factor it down and find x-values from it. I cannot find a way to factor it down and am probably just overthinking it. Any help would be much appreciated!

The deriviative I have as of right now is 
$f'(x) = 4x^3+27x^2+54x+27$

Comment: what do you have currently? can you include that in your post?

Comment: So, what derivative did you find.  (In other words, how do we determine whether the difficulty you currently have is in the differentiation or in the subsequent factoring?)

Comment: @EricTowers I updated it.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I updated it.

Comment: Why is it multiplied out?  Multiplying the factors you have after applying the product rule does not help you.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to be empty after getting the answer.  That is an abuse of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f(x) = x (x+3)^3$.  Applying the product rule, 
$$  f'(x) = x \cdot \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (x+3)^3 \right) + 1 \cdot (x+3)^3  \text{.}  $$
Then the chain rule with the power rule gives
$$ f'(x) = x \cdot 3(x+3)^2 \cdot \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (x+3) \right) + (x+3)^3  \text{.}  $$
And of course, the derivative of a line of slope $1$ is $1$, so
$$  f'(x) = 3x(x+3)^2 + (x+3)^3  \text{.}  $$
The common factor can be extracted, giving the fully factored 
$$  f'(x) = (3x + (x+3))(x+3)^2 = (4x+3)(x+3)^2 \text{.}  $$

If you already have a form with common factors (which is likely if you start with the product of something with a power), multiplying them out only creates more work for you.  Which is easier, moving around the factors of $(x+3)$ above, or factoring the cubic you got?

Comment: Thank you, I just came to this conclusion on my own as well. I was completely overthinking it, I appreciate the help!